# NestedFragment navigation With ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm developing an app which is made of SingleActivity&Fragments. 
The project flow is below.

## Project flow

[image] 
The navgraph is below.

## Navigation flow

[image]

`RegisterPhotoFragment` has a photo button. If i click the button, it show the `CameraOrGalleryBottomSheetDialog` by using `navigate(actionid)`.
In the `CameraOrGalleryBottomSheetDialog`, I can take a photo or get a image url from gallery.
For the process, I'm using `setFragmentResultListener` in `RegisterPhotoFragment` and `setFragmentResult` in `CameraOrGalleryBottomSheetDialog`. 
But the problem is, I can't get the image uri from `CameraOrGalleryBottomSheetDialog` in `RegisterPhotoFragment` and I realized that `RegisterPhotoFragment` is just made by using ViewPager2 in `BeginningFragment` not `navigate(anctionid)`. So, i didn't use `navigate(actionid)` to go to the `RegisterPhotoFragment`. 
Therefore, I changed the navigation flow like below.

### Second Navigation Flow

[image]

I restarted my app and it happened a crash.

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination mypackage:id/action_registerPhotoFragment_to_cameraOrGalleryBottomSheetDialog cannot be found from the current destination Destination(mypackage:id/beginningFragment) label=BeginningFragment class=,mypackage.presentation.ui.beginning.BeginningFragment`

because i added the RegisterPhotoFragment `res/navigation/navGraph` but i didn't use `navigate(actionid)`. If i use `naviagte(actionid)`, I can only see the screen of `RegisterPhotoFragment`. So, i didn't use it.

Finally, I decided to make a `RegisterPhotoNavHostFragment` and it has only `FragmentContainerView` and the Navigation Flow is changed again like below.

[image]

Sadly, I thought it works but it didn't. the same crash occured. 
How can i make it? is this idea wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this problem. One thing that i missed was that i have to create the `RegisterPhotoNavHostFragment` instead of `RegisterPhotoFragment` when i create the FragmentStateAdapter for ViewPager2 in `BeginningFragment`.

### before

```
private fun getFragmentsForViewPager2() = arrayListOf(
    RegisterPhotoFragment.getNewInstance(),
    RegisterNicknameFragment.getNewInstance(),
    RegisterGenderFragment.getNewInstance()
)
```

### after

```
private fun getFragmentsForViewPager2() = arrayListOf(
    RegisterPhotoNavHostFragment.getNewInstance(),
    RegisterNicknameFragment.getNewInstance(),
    RegisterGenderFragment.getNewInstance()
)
```

the idea works well.